# How to make LED sequence loop forever?

Tags: arduino

[image]

Hi, I wanted to know how to loop the LED sequence i.e. when the LED is done the first loop from left to right, it will loop again from the original position (like LED tail lights) using register.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/    even a beginner should find a solution to this within 2 minutes. all you needed to do is think, maybe supported with pen and paper. please read [ask] and don't expect people to spoon-feed you.

Comment: You can replace `i+=1` with `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
PORTD = 0b00000001 << i;
```

by

```
PORTD = 0b00000001 << (i % 8);
```

This will shift your given value `1` by at most 7 positions.